# Error al abrir VS Code desde WSL:

Tags: ubuntu, vscode, wsl

[image: Error al abrir vs code desde wsl ubuntu]

Intenté abrir un directorio desde WSL con vsCode, escribí en la terminal de WSL: "code ." desde el directorio que quería abrir y al cargar vsCode me sale este mensaje.  Ya intente con otros directorios, con otra versión de ubuntu que tengo instalada y no lo permite.

Agradezco de su ayuda.